# Disticnt id when i'm using join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to eliminate duplicate ids.I have already tried the code below, but when i'm using it it doesnt appears me anything.

```
Select disticnt i.id,b.barcode,i.code,i.name,i.price 
from inventory i 
join barcodes b on i.id=b.id
```

The problem is that i get same ids cause i have much different barcodes which fixs in one id. How can i eliminate duplicate ids

[image: Here is an image of my data]

Comment: Can you share the tables' structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: you could `group by i.id`? But the issue you will face is - which is the correct barcode record that you actually want?

Comment: when i'm trying this i get this error Column 'b.BarCode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. and the same for rest of my columns

Comment: @Dim1 - My guess would be that `b.BarCode` does not exist based on your image. but `b.barcode` does exist?

Comment: I think it doesnt matter

Comment: Anny suggestions??

Comment: You (can) have more than one barcode per ID.  Given that fact, how would you like to resolve the problem? Do you want a list of the barcodes associated with a given ID, or just the first barcode...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the barcodes table might have multiple rows for each id in the inventory table. In order to get only one record from the inventory table you must first need to figure out what barcode would you like to get back for each id that have multiple barcodes. One way is to use group by with max or min:

```
SELECT i.id,
       MAX(b.barcode) as barcode,
       i.code,
       i.name,
       i.price 
FROM inventory i 
JOIN barcodes b on i.id=b.id
GROUP BY i.id, i.code, i.name, i.price
```